# build 2 div with picture responsiv in html and css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Could anyone help me find a way to make 2 `DIV`s containing images reponsive.

At the moment, the second div is going bellow the first one , but I can't figure out how make them change size following screen size of mobile and tabs.

**here is my code :**

```css
    .new_banner_homepage {
      width: 570px;
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
      transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: 0.2s;
      transition-timing-function: linear;
      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 239px) {
      .new_banner_homepage {
        width: 90%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="new_banner_homepage">
  <a href="#">
    <img data-retina="true" src="http://placehold.it/570x150" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="new_banner_homepage">
  <a href="#">
    <img data-retina="true" src="http://placehold.it/570x150" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `.new_banner_homepage{width:570px}` and replace with `width:25%;`

Comment: What is exactly is the issue you're experiencing? Are your media queries not taking affect? What is your desired result on smaller sizes?

Comment: @benny117 Please make use of `@media` tag. Read the article here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Use @Spnkmyr advices and add a percentage width to your `.new_banner_homepage`, ie `40%`. You should change your `px` sizes to percentages or em to make it fully responsive. If you set `margin-left=30px` it will be `30px` on all screens and maybe its ok in desktop but to much for a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

To make a div responsive, you need to use percentages for width. Using pixels is a fixed width that will persist across any device. A percentage is relative and will grow, or shrink to the percentage set relative to the screen size. Ie, 25% of a desktop monitor will be more than 25% of a smartphone.

The issue you will run into is how to decrease the size of the image when the div decreases since the size of the images are fixed where as the div is now a percentage.

In order to get around this, you can use the following with the image dimensions set in the image itself.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You also want to make sure you are using something along the lines of this in your head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `meta tag` in your html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all reply,

1)I tried modify  .new_banner_homepage{width:570px} and replace with width:25%;

it just reduce size of my image to small in destokp and very very small in device mode.
2)i got effectivly :  in my head tag.

I forgot some information maybe because i'm using a template bought... : **full code here :**

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="new_banner_homepage"><a href="#"><img  data-retina="true" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/img1.png'}}" alt=""></a> </div>
 <div class="new_banner_homepage"><a href="#"><img  data-retina="true" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/img2.png'}}" alt=""></a> </div>


</div>
```

**and css :**

```
.container{

width: 1170px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.new_banner_homepage{
width: 25%;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-delay: 0s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 25%){
    .new_banner_homepage{ width: 25%; }
```

}

thx